# Webpack jumbling up all CSS from different React Components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

Below is my Webpack Config:

```
const path = require('path');
// const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = env => ({
    entry: './main.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: './'
    },
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: [/\.js$|.jsx$/],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['babel-preset-es2015', 'babel-preset-stage-2', 'babel-preset-react'],
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'icons/',
            },
        },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/template.html'
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        watchContentBase: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        disableHostCheck: true,
    },
});
```

When I run webpack and generate the bundle it pulls up CSS from all over the app and puts it in the head section.
I'm using SCSS and every component has it's own SCSS file.
Below is the folder tree:

[image: Folder structure]

This is how my React app looks like in the browser:

[image: multiple style tags]

I know I'm doing something stupid but can't figure out what. How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated. I'm using Webpack 4.

Comment: not sure how query params work for webpack but you have to give modules=1 your config line just says modules `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',`

Answer (score 1):

That is what happens when you use `style-loader`. It adds css to head.

You should use `mini-css-extract-plugin` to generate external css file.

Comment: Actually I'm not too bothered about the output location of the CSS. Problem is, it is putting CSS from all components into style tags at the same place, which is causing name collisions and other issues.

Comment: exactly. Because it process every single component, it puts everyting together